# How to cause same effect of child on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, slide, effect

is there a way to cast the same effect of a child on a parent?

```
<div id = "parent">    
    <div id = "child">
    </div>
    //button.click to .show("slide") child
</div>
```

How can I cast that same effect on the parent for the same event fired?

Comment: You need to give a little more detail on what you are wanting the script to do.  Also show what javascript you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$("#child").click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

or this:

```
$("#child").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) it